# Table view cells duplicate UIViews while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, tableview

I have a view controller with a table view. In the method to set up the cell/cell text I create an UIView and an UILabel in this view. Then I add the UIView to the cell. So every cell in the table view got an UIView in it. So I create chat bubbles.

But now when I start my application and scroll a few time up and down in my table view, somehow my UIViews get duplicated. Every time I scroll up and down the application "creates" new UIViews.

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong? I will post my objective-c code later.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would you please post your code, maybe your problem is that you are ignoring the fact that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will fetch an old cell rather than creating a new one, so please post your full code to tell you where the problem is

Comment: Could you please post your cellforrowatindexpath method?

Answer (score 0):

What a tableview does, to be as efficient as possible, is to re-use previous cells as new ones.  So imagine that, as you scroll downwards, a cell that disappears at the top of the screen is quickly taken from off-screen, and placed at the bottom of the screen (again off-screen), to become that cell that newly appears.  So while you get the impression that a long table full of cells is behind the scenes, in fact - you can see almost all the cells that exist, except for one or two just off-screen at the top and bottom.

So now you've pictured that, imagine that the cell that you configured, in your case by adding views to it, is taken from its place at the top and moved to the bottom to become a new cell. But no-one has told that cell to get rid of the added views you have given it.  So those extra views are still there, and then you call -cellForRowAtIndexPath again, and two more views are added, to become 4.  Then next time 6, then 8, and on and on.  This is your problem.

Two ways to handle this are : use storyboards or nibs, and put your custom cell appearance in one of these interface builder files.  The compiler will know not to duplicate those extra views.  Most UITableViewCells are controlled this way.  It might take a little time to find a tutorial and to learn this technique, but its well worth it in the long run.

Another way is to create your own subclass of UITableViewCell.  Then you can over-ride methods in there - for example.  Over-riding the init method allows you to add your views programmatically in that method, and that means that the method is not called when your cells are re-used, because obviously they are not init'd twice (they remain existing throughout re-use).  You then get access to another handy method, -prepareForReuse, which is called just before your cells get swapped and used for a different table cell, allowing you to (for example) clear data that you have populated for previous cells.